# highcharts - zoom issue after changing series data

Tags: highcharts, zooming

There is a strange behavior ar may be even bug in highcharts. If I change series data while chart is zoomed, I can't zoom it anymore:(((

Here are steps to reproduce

1. Goto http://jsfiddle.net/CXKmD/2/
2. Zoom chart using mouse
3. Click "Change" button to change chart's data
4. Try to zoom again using mouse

The problem is that after these steps **event.xAxis** is undefined, so we can't get min/max values of mouse zoom selection.

Are there any workarounds to let chart change it's data in zoomed state and then zoom it even further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug
You are unnecessarily converting the timestamps to date objects, whereas the setExteremeMethod expects timestamps, while now you are passing it a date. Changed your code to this and it worked

```
if (event.xAxis[0]) {
    startDt = event.xAxis[0].min;
    endDt = event.xAxis[0].max;
}
```

fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/tdkwy/